# Function getLanguage() does not return current language?

Tags: joomla-2.5, php

I'm trying to get the current selected language.

Here is the part of my code:

```
define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/defines.php')) {
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/defines.php';
}

if (!defined('_JDEFINES')) {
    define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__));
    require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/defines.php';
}

require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/framework.php';

$lang =& JFactory::getLanguage()->getTag();
```

and...

```
echo $lang;
```

allways returns en-GB.

The website has the possibility of Ger and Eng. It also changes languages for different articles. I don't understand how I did not get the current selected language within php.

Comment: Topically relevant StackOverflow page with J4 answer: [How to detect the current language of a Joomla! website?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3352241/2943403)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think that it is possible. You are trying to get language outside of the application scope. You can try to instantiate the application:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
```

But I doubt that it will help.

Comment: I thank you sir it helped.. but their is another line which has to be added after `$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');` it is : `$app->initialise();`

Comment: Yeah forgot it. Glad that you made it.