# How to use JFactory::getLanguage() from another directory?

Tags: joomla-2.5, php

How can I get the current selected language using the Function `JFactory::getLanguage();` from another directory?

I know how to do it when I am there:

- /web/include
- /web                      <---- [can call it from here] ([solved here](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5036/function-getlanguage-does-not-return-current-language))

but I need to call it from...

- /web/scripts/myScripts/myScript.php

Tried to import Joomla Framework:

```
// Set flag that this is a parent file.
define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../defines.php')) {
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../defines.php';
}

if (!defined('_JDEFINES')) {
    define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__));
    require_once JPATH_BASE.'/../../includes/defines.php';
}
require_once JPATH_BASE.'/../../includes/framework.php';

// Instantiate the application.
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');

// Initialise the application.
$app->initialise();

$lang =& JFactory::getLanguage()->getTag();
```

Comment: So are you trying to get the currently language from an external PHP file that isn't associated with Joomla?

Comment: Yes, seems like that :) Is it even possible?

Comment: You will have to import the Joomla framework to do this ;)

Comment: I tried but I couldn't from there. Help me with that and than.. help me to get this login-function from your website too :D

Comment: Please add the code you tried to import the Joomla framework and get the language. Then mention any errors that may have occured

Comment: I edited it... I dont get any errors there... just get a blank page

Comment: You are getting a blank page because your error reporting isn't enabled. You also need to define `JPATH_BASE`

Comment: next try Still stame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition for `JPATH_BASE` is still missing from your code. 
To import the Joomla API, you can simply use the following:

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/..' ));

require_once ( JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php' );

$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$app->initialise();
```

Then to get the language tag:

```
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
$tag  = $lang->getTag();
```

You need to make sure `JPATH_BASE` has been defined correctly. I'm not sure where your external PHP file is located in relation to your Joomla installation, but you will need to change line 2 of the API importing code.

Hope this helps

Comment: Now another question, based on the `$tag`... Can I compare this like `$tag=="en-GB"`

Comment: You're welcome. As for the login on my website, the styling is based on [UIKit](http://getuikit.com) and the implementation is custom

Comment: Well, I thought it is an easy module from joomla ^^ looks like it is more complex and it needs time :)

Comment: Can I `if ($tag == "en-GB")` ??

Comment: Yes you can do this. For example: `if($tag == 'en-GB') { echo "English"; } `