# Function getLanguage() on domain?

Tags: joomla-2.5, php

Function getLanguage() works on .de but not on .com domain?

Did I forgot sth. right in the code?

[The Code](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5228/how-to-use-jfactorygetlanguage-from-another-directory)

Directories:

[image]

Comment: How does the `.com` domain compare to the `.de` one? I assume they are not 2 different site. Is 1 pointing to the other?

Comment: I'm not realy sure, but I guess `.de` points to `.com`.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `.de` points to `.com` and they are not 2 different websites?

Comment: No, I'm not. But I am working on `.de` and everything (except the getLanguage()-function) works. Switching language has no effect. `echo $tag;` : output `de-DE`, even after selecting english (on `.com` domain).

Comment: This is a fundamental bit of information that is required. If the domains are 2 completely different Joomla sites then of course the code will not work. The code you're using will get the language from the Joomla installation that you have specfied, thus if they are 2 different installations, then you will also need to import the Joomla API from the `.com` site

Comment: You mean, it should work if one domain points to the other. And if they are 2 different websites I have to import the Joomla API from `.com` to make it work. Which means I got 2 different installations!??

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to write this as an answer to I can go into further detail and explain things clearly :)

Ok so you have 2 websites:

- www.example.de
- www.example.com

It appears that the `.de` domain is your primary website. So, then you go to the `.com` website, it will either redirect to the `.de` website **or** simply display the website.

If you navigate to **www.example.com/administrator**, again, it should either redirect **or** not. If it doesn't then they are most likely 2 different websites.

So far you should be able to tell us what happens when you view the `.com` domain.

Assuming there is no redirect, go your your File Manager (hosting cpanel or FTP) and you will see the files/folders for your Joomla site. You may also see a sub-folder with a separate Joomla installation side it. If you do then you will also need to import the API from this sub-folder too.

Comment: 1. I can't get into www.example.com/administrator - I get 404 not found. 2. I can't find a files/folders within FTP. (found web\plugins\editors\jckeditor\install\models\folders.php)

Comment: files/folders isn't a directory. I simply meant your Joomla files and folders. When I said `www.example.com/administrator`, I didn't mean this exact domain. You obviously need to change `example` to whatever your domain is.

Comment: It is obvious what you mean with `example` :) But I didn't get which folder I have to find now.

Comment: The folder could be anything. Like I said, It's not certain that you will have a sub-folder with another installation inside but possible. Can you take a screenshot of the root of your Joomla installation please so I can see