# Get current language in external script (Joomla 3.3)

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-api, language

In Joomla 2.5 it is possible to get the current language of a visitor in an external script like this:

```
$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
$jdocument = JFactory::getDocument();
$jdocument->getLanguage();
```

I couldn't find out how to get the language in Joomla 3.3. The framework loads, but the language is always defined as 'en'.

I’ve also tried various other options like:

```
$japplication = JApplicationWeb::getInstance();
$japplication->initialise();
```

Did anyone experience the same issue? Is this a Bug?

Comment: Not diffcult, see my answer here https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/21486/11516

Comment: Topically relevant StackOverflow page with J4 answer: [How to detect the current language of a Joomla! website?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3352241/2943403)

Answer (score 1):

I had kinda the same problem, but in the end I figured out how to make it work for my specific application using an alternative method.
Watch my solution here:
[Getting current language in Joomla 3 in external script seems difficult.. but works fine in J2.5](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/7174/getting-current-language-in-joomla-3-in-external-script-seems-difficult-but-wo?lq=1)

Hope you can use the same method :)

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked [here](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5036/function-getlanguage-does-not-return-current-language/5037#5037) a while ago and the key was to get and initialise the application like so:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$app->initialise();

$lang = JFactory::getLanguage()->getTag();
echo $lang;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
The question you linked relates to Joomla 2.5, in Joomla 2.5 my posted approach is working fine, but it is not in Joomla 3.3, I always get ‘en-GB’ instead of ‘de-DE’